# Spinner Text Becomes Blank/White after Recreating Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Why does the spinner text become blank after making a selection?

The spinner text flashes and then becomes blank if I use getActivity().recreate(); after making a selection.

I'm using recreate to load a locale based on the spinner selection.

```
onCreateView

spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

((TextView) spinner.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

getActivity().recreate();

switch (position) {

                case 0:
                    setLocale("en");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    setLocale("en-us");
                    break;
}
}

 @Override
                                              public void 
onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


                                              }
});
```

In an Activity, I would use getIntent and startactivity and the spinner text doesn't become blank.

Answer (score 0):

you can try putting setRetainInstance(true) on the oncreate method of your fragment

Comment: Thanks but it's still blank/white after the fragment refreshes

Comment: Can you add the code where you initialize the spinner.

Comment: Still blank/white :(

Comment: can you paste your current code here so that I can check

Comment: Code has been added